# play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have a play framework application [version 1.2.7].
when I try to get data in a non-jpa Entity form I get this exception

```html
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 16
 at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
 at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 16
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1389)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255)
```

my code is as follows

```html
 List lst = JPA.em().createNativeQuery(myQuery)
                .setParameter("p", searchPhrase)
                .getResultList();
```

I want to use native query and get all extract all data but I dont want to be limited to getting it as an Jpa Entity.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste persistance.xml, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong the JDBC type 16 is `BOOLEAN` (look at`java.sql.Types`). Your problem might be caused by use of wrong hibernate.dialect which doesn't know `BOOLEAN` types which occur in one of tables you are trying to select. Check `hibernate.dialect` property in your `persistence.xml` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: Thanks very much , I changed the boolean type into int and everything works now.